# How to implement System.Text.Json source generator with a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, system.text.json, csharp-source-generator

I have a generic class like this:

```
public class Property<TObjectType>
{
}
```

I would like to use the new `System.Text.Json` [source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/) but it does not seem to work for a generic class. Here is the derived `JsonSerializerContext` for that class:

```
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Property<>))]
public partial class PropertyJsonContext<TObjectType> : JsonSerializerContext
{
}
```

The error is a bit weird as it makes all the other non-generic `JsonSerializerContext` implementations fail with these 2 errors:

```
Error CS0534: 'XXXJsonContext' does not implement inherited abstract member 'JsonSerializerContext.GeneratedSerializerOptions.get'

Error CS0534: 'XXXJsonContext' does not implement inherited abstract member 'JsonSerializerContext.GetTypeInfo(Type)'
```

There is also this warning that I feel is related to my problem:

```
CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'JsonSourceGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'ArgumentException' with message 'The hintName 'PropertyJsonContext`1.NSPropertyTObjectType.g.cs' contains an invalid character '`' at position 21.
```

Then I changed the derived class to remove the genericity:

```
[JsonSerializable(typeof(NSProperty<>))]
public partial class NSPropertyJsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}
```

And I get this error:

```
  The type or namespace name 'TObjectType' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented JSON source code generation today in my application using .net 7. The trick is to specify the possible concrete types and give it a name:

```cs
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Property<Foo>), TypeInfoPropertyName = "PropertyOfFoo")]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Property<Bar>), TypeInfoPropertyName = "PropertyOfBar")]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Property<IDictionary<string, string>>), TypeInfoPropertyName = "PropertyBag")]
public partial class PropertyJsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}
```

In case of `Bar` you can pass `PropertyJsonContext.Default.PropertyOfBar` to the JsonSerializer methods. I changed my APIs that the caller (which passes chooses a concrete type for TObjectState) also pass in `JsonTypeInfo<T>`, in the example above that would be `JsonTypeInfo<Property<TObjectState>>`.